# How to auto sync local SQl Database with Microsoft Azure Sql database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ado.net, azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

I have a ADO.net application which generates some data in regular intervals that is stored in a local SQL server. I want that database to sync with Microsoft azure SQL database automatically. What would be the best process to make it happen?

Comment: I suspect that Microsoft may have some documentation on this...

Answer (score 2):

You have two options. One of them is SQL Data Sync which will sync you local database with an Azure SQL Database and viceversa. It is a bi-directional replication that works best with SQL Server 2008 R2 (and later) on-premises databases. This service is in preview and you can get started with it by visiting [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync) documentation.

Your second option is Snapshot and one-way replication that works with SQL Server 2012 and later. You can get started with it on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/replication-to-sql-database) documentation.

Hope this helps.